# Como hacer que se muestren todos los datos en mysql y no solo el último

Tags: php, html, mysql, variables, select

EL problema es el siguiente: Yo hago un SELECT en el cual obtengo todos los valores de una tabla que sean iguales a un nombre, y lo almaceno en la variable $gruposcookies. Luego, hago otro SELECT en el obtengo todos los valores de otro tabla que tengan una columna que sea igual a alguna de las palabras contenidas en la variable $gruposcookies. Cuando imprimo la variable $gruposcookies me da el siguiente valor: JavaProgramación (general)Futbol. Pero cuando imprimo el valor de $publicacion, que es la variable en la que se almacena lo que devuelve el SELECT, solo muestra los datos cuya columna es igual a Fubol, la ultima palabra de $gruposcookies, pero no aquellos datos cuya columna sea igual a Java o a Programación. Es como si solo se almacenara en la variableecon el ultimo valor, pero cuando posteriormente se imprime esta variable si que imprimieran el resto de datos.
Si alguien sabe cual es el error y como podrías solucionarlo estaría muy agradecido.
Este es el codigo:

```
<?php 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cookies_grupos WHERE usuario = '".$usuario."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $gruposcookies = $mostrar['grupo'];   
        $sql="SELECT * FROM publicaciones WHERE nombre = '".$autor."' AND grupo LIKE '%".$gruposcookies."%' ORDER BY RAND() limit 1";echo $gruposcookies;
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    if($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
        $publicacion = $mostrar['publicacion'];
    }
    echo $publicacion;

?>
```

Comment: Creo que luego de ordenar e identar el codigo como corresponde, se nota que no hace lo que vos pensas que hace, no?

Comment: @gbianchi Exactamente, pero no se porque.

Comment: agrega comentarios de que pensas que pasa en cada linea, y te va ayudar mucho a entender que pasa...

Comment: las variables solo pueden tener un valor, y $sql se queda con el ultimo.. te das cuenta?

Comment: @gbianchi No te entiendo. Ya se que solo pueden tener un valor, y de hecho solo tienen uno, que es: JavaProgramación (general)Futbol. Una palabra formada por muchas. No se que problema ves.

Comment: Y que datos tiene la tabla?

Comment: @gbianchi Uno de los datos es Java, otro Programación (general) y otro Futbol. Perro luego en la variable se juntan.

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo mucho de php, pero creo que tienes un error muy simple, la segunda consulta debe estar dentro del bucle while.

```
<?php 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cookies_grupos WHERE usuario = '".$usuario."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $gruposcookies = $mostrar['grupo'];   
        $sql="SELECT * FROM publicaciones WHERE nombre = '".$autor."' AND grupo LIKE '%".$gruposcookies."%' ORDER BY RAND() limit 1";echo $gruposcookies;
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        if($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
           $publicacion = $mostrar['publicacion'];
        }
        echo $publicacion;
    }
?>
```

Comment: No funciona aun así, pero muchas gracias por su ayuda.